# How to check if a texture with a specific name does not exist yet?

Tags: python, texturing, modifiers, displacement

I am trying to use python to create a cloud texture for a displacement modifier, but the problem is that right now each time the script runs it creates a new texture.

What I would like to do is check if the texture already exists, and if so then use it, but if not then create it.

So I tried to check that the name of the texture does not already exist with an if statement like this:

```
if (bpy.data.textures['Clouds'].name == None):
```

However, this doesn't work because if the 'Clouds' texture does not already exist then python gives me this error:

**KeyError: key "Clouds" not found**.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this test.

You can use `get` rather than indexing:

```
texture = bpy.data.textures.get('Clouds')
if not texture:
   print("No texture clouds")
```

or you can use indexing and exception handling:

```
try:
    texture = bpy.data.textures['Clouds']
except KeyError:
    print("No texture clouds")
```

There are various reasons to prefer the version with get and the if statement, but if there is not a performance issue, the version with exception handling can be more readable.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue. Appreciated.

Comment: There is also `if "Clouds" not in bpy.data.textures:`

Comment: drat, I usually remember to put "at least" in front of the number because there's always at least one more way.  thanks @Gorgious